# Sequelize – understored timestamps

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have my model defined with all of the attributes in snake case. I've also set `timestamps: true` and `underscored: true` in the config, yet those options do not convert the `createdAt`, `updatedAt` and `deletedAt` to snake case.

What is the correct way of converting the automatically generated timestamps to snake case?

Answer (score 1):

This is for **`createdAt` , `updatedAt` and `deletedAt`** :

If you are using **Version5**: (**[DOC](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html)**)

```
underscored: true, // <--- You need only this
```

> Override the name of the createdAt attribute if a string is provided,
>   or disable it if false. Timestamps must be true. Underscored field
>   will be set with underscored setting.

---

And if the **Below version5** : (**[DOC](https://sequelize.org/v4/class/lib/model.js~Model.html)**)

> Override the name of the createdAt column if a string is provided, or
>   disable it if false. Timestamps must be true. Not affected by
>   underscored setting.

You **need to do some extra work** like this :

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true
});

// ------------------------ OR -----------------------

var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    createdAt: {
        field: 'created_at',
        type: Sequelize.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
        field: 'updated_at',
        type: Sequelize.DATE
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true
});
```

Comment: The only way I was trying to do this is to manually pass `createdAt: 'created_at'` to the model config

Comment: i don't know about that, try this out. @Ancinek , similar issue : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2641

Comment: I appreciate your help, but you are passing pretty old issues, from 2014. I've already read a bunch of them and SO is kind of my last resort when it comes to solving the problem

Comment: @Ancinek, which version are you using ?

Comment: The latest one - 5.15.0

Comment: then just use `underscored: true,` it should work , there is no need to define any extra thing